как узнать что окно браузера в полноэкранном режиме
сама суть задачи в следующем:
есть модалка, которая должна появляться, если окно браузера не в полноэкранном режиме, перейти же в этот режим можно по кнопке в этой модалке или же на f11 (если мы на пк сидим соответственно); если режим активировать, то модалка исчезает
все эти Fullscreen API какое то д***мо, ибо работают только, если сделать активацию через кнопку, но если же нажать через f11, то никакой метод уже не может ничего уловить... через @media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) тоже вроде бы работает, но только на пк, а на телефоне ничего не происходит... может есть какая-нибудь библиотека? или всё гораздо легче? или вообще это не решаемо?... памагите(

А чем на телефоне определяется полноэкранность?

@Qwertiy, не совсем понял вашего вопроса. я как раз и хочу узнать, как мне эту информацию получить (инфу, что полноэкранный режим включён или отключён), как на телефонах, так и на пк. всё, что в моём вопросе описано, то я и пытался делать.

Я в принципе не понимаю, что имеется в виду под полноэкранным режимом на телефоне. Если немного проскроллить страницу и адресная строка исчезнет - это полноэкранный режим или нет?

А если браузер открыт в режиме разделения экрана?

@Qwertiy, полноэкранный режим, это когда на пк нажимаешь f11, то же самое есть на телефонах, но только если использовать Fullscreen API, который коряво работает



window.onresize = function(){
    if(window.innerHeight == screen.height){
        mymodal.hidden = true;
         // или так:
        mymodal.style.display = "none";
    }
}




Это сработает только если масштаб 100%.

в целом оно работает, теперь окно исчезает и появляется, но есть одно но: на телефонах есть шторка сверху, где написан url (картинка) и если вниз пролистать немного, чтобы эта шторка пропала, то окно появляется. понятно, что можно дополнительные условия подставить, но всё таки, это тоже не совсем рабочий способ получается :(

@ralph, пропала или появилась? Поменяй масштаб вообще на любой кроме 100% и окно будет всегда.

@Qwertiy, масштаб чего? контейнеров? у меня сейчас весь масштаб сделан на 100vw/vh, т.к. всё должно быть растянуто на весь экран.

@ralph, иасштаб страницы в браузере.

@Qwertiy, всё таки отказаться от 100%/vw/vh я не могу и, вообще, окно мне не нужно всегда, а только, когда полноэкранный режим не включён :)

@ralph, да при чём тут это??? ctrl+плюс или ctrl+минус нажми!

@ralph а чем document.fullscreenElement не угодил?

@eccs0103, тем, что от этого метода ничего не происходит о_0

@Qwertiy, "ctrl+плюс или ctrl+минус" — для чего? имеете в виду, что, если страница как то изменится, то окна появится, даже если не будет полноэкранного режима? я это и так понимаю, более того, я это сам и написал выше

Не понимаю к чему все эти трюки с высотой и со всеми, поэтому напишу самый стандартный и рабочий вариант.
/**
 * Фукнция подгоняет какой-нибудь элемент в полноэкранный режим
 * @param {Element?} element 
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
function setFullscreen(element) {
    return (element === null)
        ? document.exitFullscreen()
        : element.requestFullscreen();
}

/**
 * Функция возвращяет элемент в полноэкранном режиме
 * @returns {Element?}
 */
function getFullscreen() {
    return document.fullscreenElement;
}

/**
 * Функция проверяет наличие какого-нибудь элемента в полноэкранном режиме
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isFullscreen() {
    return document.fullscreenElement !== null;
}


Первая функция странно работает - весь экран становится чёрным, как буд-то выключают монитор.

@Опан возможно у вас верстка неправильная. Такое поведение от этой функции не видел никогда.

С этим я уже разобрался, но всё равно не понял, как эти функции должны помочь убрать модальное окно во время нажатия на F11?

@Опан после изменения размеров экрана можно например с помощью функции isFullscreen проверить режим и убрать это модальное окно. И не важно переход через F11 или как то ещё

В том-то и дело, что isFullscreen() выдаёт false, она проверяет наличие отдельных элементов в полноэкранном режиме, а не всего окна.
